# Akka custom logger does not receive some messages

Tags: logging, akka

I have written a custom logger for [akka](/questions/tagged/akka) to pass on log messages to a remote system. I have a second logger in place using [slf4j](/questions/tagged/slf4j) with [logback](/questions/tagged/logback) as backend to print to the console and a logfile.

The strange thing I noticed is that some messages are not being received by my custom logger but the slf4j one receives them just fine.

For example the error messages generated by a failing child actor that get logged as part of the supervision strategy:

```
[DEBUG][akka://Test/system/remote-deployment-watcher]: started (akka.remote.RemoteDeploymentWatcher@b342d63)
[DEBUG][akka://Test/system]: now supervising Actor[akka://Test/system/deadLetterListener#-286980524]
started (akka.remote.RemoteDeploymentWatcher@b342d63)
now supervising Actor[akka://Test/system/deadLetterListener#-286980524]
[DEBUG][akka://Test/system/deadLetterListener]: started (akka.event.DeadLetterListener@4a3c6344)
started (akka.event.DeadLetterListener@4a3c6344)
started (akka.remote.RemoteWatcher@14fbdfea)
[DEBUG][akka://Test/system/remote-watcher]: started (akka.remote.RemoteWatcher@14fbdfea)
now supervising TestActor[akka://Test/user/$$a]
[DEBUG][akka://Test/user]: now supervising TestActor[akka://Test/user/$$a]
started (package.Discoverer@24537c20)
now supervising Actor[akka://Test/user/$$a/refresher#-138594901]
[DEBUG][akka://Test/user/$$a]: started (package.Discoverer@24537c20)
[DEBUG][akka://Test/user/$$a]: now supervising Actor[akka://Test/user/$$a/refresher#-138594901]
akka.tcp://Test@127.0.0.1:2552/user/$$a: im an error
[ERROR][akka.tcp://Test@127.0.0.1:2552/user/$$a]: im an error
stopped
[ERROR][akka://Test/user/$$a/refresher]: exception during creation
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
    at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:164) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.3.5.jar:na]
    ...
```

For debugging purposes my custom logger prints the received messages to the console. The messages with the prefixed log level are generated by slf4j and the ones in between that contain just the message are generated by my custom logger.

As you can see my custom logger receives the debug messages just fine and even the error message *"im an error"* that I manually generated is received fine but not the automatic message generated by the exception.

**Do I have to subscribe the logger to additional events to receive those? Or what is the issue here?**

My logger:

```
class MonitoringLogger extends Actor {

  val mon = context.actorOf(Props[MonitorEndpoint], "MonitorEndpoint")

  def receive = {
    case InitializeLogger(bus) => sender ! LoggerInitialized
    case Error(cause, logSource, logClass, message: String) =>
      println(message)
      mon ! format(logSource, message, Console.RED)
    case Warning(logSource, logClass, message: String) => mon ! format(logSource, message, Console.YELLOW)
    case Info(logSource, logClass, message: String) => mon ! format(logSource, message, Console.GREEN)
    case Debug(logSource, logClass, message: String) =>
      println(message)
      mon ! format(logSource, message, Console.GREEN)
  }

  def format(src: String, msg: String, code: String) = s"${Console.BLUE}R> $code[${src.split('/').last}] ${Console.RESET}$msg"
}
```

Interresting part of application.conf:

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger", "package.MonitoringLogger"]
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
  log-dead-letters = 10
  actor.debug {
    lifecycle = on
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your custom logger?

Comment: @cmbaxter I certainly can.

Comment: My guess is that you have an unhandled case. Try adding a `case other =>` and then print what the `other` is to see if there is another message type for the stuff you are missing.

Comment: @cmbaxter Thanks for the tip. You lead me to my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cmbaxter has lead me to my mistake. The `case class Error` that I match against is defined as:

```
case class Error(
  cause: Throwable, 
  logSource: String, 
  logClass: Class[_], 
  message: Any = "") extends LogEvent
```

Note that the `message` has type `Any` but I match against `String`. My own log messages get matched against because I use a string message. The auto generated event of that exception has `message` set to `null` so it doesn't satisfy the match.